# Just reinstalled my 12.04 - I want to have back the option to choose between unity, gnome, gnome-classic & gnome classic-no effects - help?

Tags: gnome, 12.04, command-line

How do I go about installing not only the Gnome-classic fallback but also installing the regular Gnome, and Gnome-classic-noeffects?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should get it all by installing gnome. Run this in the terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install gnome
```

This should install Gnome 3, Gnome Classic/Fallback, and Gnome Classic (No effects).

If the problem is that the option to chose desktop environment is not yet present, I assume you have turned automatic login on. Turn this off. There is a tutorial [here](http://howtoideas.net/how-to-enable-automatic-login-in-ubuntu).

Answer (score 2):

Open System Settings > User account, click unlock and make sure you haven't selecten Automatic login.

You should be able to change your desktop manager clicking on the Ubuntu logo above the password input.

If you can't, open a terminal and enter

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-session-fallback gnome-shell
```

When installed try again.